# Enable Tidy on openshift

Tags: openshift, tidy

I'm trying to get the Tidy module to load for my PHP app that I'm hosting on Openshift. Editing the PHP.ini seems to not be allowed as when I restart the app, the file reverts to the old content.

I've tried adding the following to my php script but it doesn't seem to work:

```
ini_set('tidy.clean_output', '1');
```

I've also added this to the .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value tidy.clean_output On
</IfModule>
```

Any help gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this page (http://php.net/manual/en/tidy.installation.php), Tidy must be installed using the "--with-tidy" option when configuring PHP, along with, on Red Hat Linux, installing both libtidy and libtidy-devel.  If you create a phpinfo page (http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) you can see by the generated output that Tidy is not enabled.  You would not be able to enable this module just by updating your php.ini.

The best option would be to visit openshift.uservoice.com and add Tidy as a feature that you would like to have enabled, then you can have other users go vote on it.

Even if you compiled your own version of PHP on your gear Tidy would not work unless those two packages were installed as listed above.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I've added the feature request to uservoice.